# How to I assign values to letters that come from a csv file?

Tags: python, assign

I am calculating the gpa of a given curriculum. I want to multiply the number of credits by the grade that the student achieved. I want to make the program know that A in the csv file is equal to 4, B is equal to 3 and so on.

[image]

I tried telling the program that the letters on the slice of data equal a number, but it didn't work

I have written this so far:

```py
def over_gpa(data):
  total_cred = np.sum(data[:,3])

  messi = np.unique(data[:,3:])

  for k in messi:
    value = []
    
    y = data[:,3]
    f = data[:,4]
    
    x = y * f
    value.append(x)
    m = np.sum(value)
  
  total_gpa = m/total_cred
  print(total_gpa)

over_gpa(data)
```

Comment: 1) What code have you written so far? 2) Can you provide the data as CSV, rather than an image?

Comment: Try a dictionary, where letter grade is the key, and numeric value is the value.  Example: `grades = {'A': 4, 'B':3,...}`.  Then use `score = grades.get(letterGrade, 0)`, so any grade letter not in the dictionary gets converted to 0.

Comment: A lookup table and vlookup().

Answer (score 0):

I'd initialize a dict that maps letters to grades and then apply it to a new column.

```
vals = { "A" : 4, "B" : 3, "C" : 2, "D" : 1, "F" : 0 }
df['Grade number'] = df['Grade'].apply(lambda x: vals.get(x))
```

Comment: How would you implement this in my code?

Comment: What's the structure of `data`? Is it a pandas dataframe or matrix? If a dataframe, then use what I posted above:

`vals = { "A" : 4, "B" : 3, "C" : 2, "D" : 1, "F" : 0 }
data['Grade number'] = data['Grade'].apply(lambda x: vals.get(x))`

Otherwise, you'll need to append each entry in your matrix with something like:

`result = [row[0:-1] + [vals[row[-1]]] for row in data]`